# html: how to restrict upload file format to plain text

Tags: javascript, html, web

I need to have a upload file functionality on my web page. I only want people to be able to choose .csv and plain text(.txt) file.

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv,text/plain" >
```

I know the attribute accept may work. But there are two problems.

1. It doesn't work with Firefox or Safari
2. csv works fine, but text seems not restricted. I can upload .java file, .rtf file, .python file, etc..

Anyone knows how to implement that ?

Comment: If you find a fix for your problem i would highly recommend validating server-side before saving anything! All client-side data can be edited using inspect element. If you don't validate this server-side i can open inspect element, remove the attribute and upload `any` file i want, example: PHP now i can have my code run on your website, echo data i wouldn't normally have access to? Or just delete your website? Please make sure you validate server-side, you'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 2):

Be mindful that anything that you do on the client side, for example using the `accept` attribute in the `input` tag, can easily be ignored/overridden by the client.  So, if you really want to prevent files other than the types that you specify from being uploaded to your server, then you should do some sort of checking on the server side, in the script that your form posts to.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to accept txt files, change your accept from text/plain to `accept=".csv,.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$target="images/";  //path to upload
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) //check if post is set
{
        if $_FILES['file']['type'] != 'text/plain'
        {  
             // error
         } else {
           //upload
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
          }   

}
```